# proving is cauchy sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

To show that sequence $\left(1+{1 \over 3n}\right)^n$ converges using cauchy criteria.

> For a given $\epsilon$, $\exists$ natural number $k$ such that,
> $$|a_m-a_n|<\epsilon, \forall m,n \ge k$$.

for given sequence, $|a_m-a_n|$=$\left|(1+{1 \over 3m})^m-(1+{1 \over 3n})^n \right|$=$\left|1+3+{m(m-1)\over 2}{1 \over{(3m)^2}}. . .|-|1+3+{n(n-1)\over 2}{1 \over{(3n)^2}}. . .\right|$

what after this?

Answer (score 0):

By AM-GM inequality, for all $n\in\mathbb N$,
\begin{align*}
\textstyle
\left(\frac{1}{1+1/(3n)}\right)^{(3n+1)/(3n+2)}=\left(\frac{3n}{3n+1}\right)^{(3n+1)/(3n+2)}\leq\frac{1+(3n+1)(3n/(3n+1))}{3n+2}=\frac{3n+1}{3n+2}=\frac{1}{1+1/(3n+1)}.
\end{align*}
Thus, $a_n:=\left(\frac{1}{1+1/(3n)}\right)^{3n+1}$ is a decreasing sequence.
Since $a_n$ has a lower bound $0$, it is a Cauchy sequence.
Then your sequence $a_n^{1/(3+1/n)}$ is also a Cauchy sequence.